# Mapping for <S-F3> is not behaving as it should do

Tags: vim

I have this mapping in my `.vimrc` file *(applicable to all filetypes)*.

```
nnoremap <F3> a<C-R>=strftime("%a %d %b %Y %r")<CR><Esc>
inoremap <F3> <C-R>=strftime("%a %d %b %Y %r")<CR>
```

And my `python.vim` *(located in `after/ftplugin/`)* has this:

```
nnoremap <S-F3> :up<cr>
inoremap <S-F3> <esc>:up<cr>a
```

The mapping for <kbd>F3</kbd> works as expected in both normal and insert mode. But for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> mapping it should save the current file. But it is inserting some unexpected characters above the current line, which is **`1;2R`**. I don't know what it does stands for.

---

#### UPDATE

This is the output of `:verbose nmap <S-F3>`:

```
n  <S-F3>      * :up<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim
```

With exactly that indentation.

Comment: It looks like a range. Could you do `:verbose nmap <S-F3>`?

Answer (score 4):

This is related to the way the terminals handle keys. You can always see what is actually being sent to the program when you press a key by pressing C-v and then the key. This also works outside Vim.

Solution:

1 - In your vimrc type `nnoremap` part of your mapping with a space at the end.

2 - Hit C-v and then S-F3. On my machine this prints  `^[[25~`, which is what your terminal is sending to Vim.

3 - Add one more space before typing `:up<cr>`.

It should look like this: `nnoremap ^[[25~ :up<cr>`

Comment: When I press C-v I enter the *Visual Block* mode, after that when I pressed S-F3 the same thing happened i.e. **`1;2R`**. Well I tried mapping `^[[25~` but that gives the same result as it was before.

Comment: It should work in insert mode. Sorry for not being clear about that.

Comment: The `^[` part of that is actually the visual representation of the <Esc> key. Can you tell me what happens in Vim insert mode when you press <C-v> and then <S-F3> ?

Comment: Ok, that's probably what <S-F3> means to your terminal. You should be able to use it in your mapping. For more info try `:h i_ctrl-v`.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks a lot. For reference, the final mapping for Shift-F3 in gnome-terminal looks like this: map ^[O1;2R :bp<CR>